# Still confused about Timezone and conversions

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, timezone

I collect user time zone and a time they want something delivered in that time zone.

My application is set to use Bangkok Time.

application.rb

```
 config.time_zone = 'Bangkok'
```

I want to store the time the user has entered relative to my timezone.

So say for example the user selects the following:

```
time = "6:00"
timezone = "(GMT-10:00) Hawaii"
```

I want to convert this time to the time of my application and save it in the database.

How can I convert from 6AM Hawaii time zone to what time this is in Bangkok?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us use your example to demonstrate:

```
config.time_zone = 'Bangkok'
time = "6:00"
timezone = "Hawaii"
```

The first thing you need to do is set the timezone of your app to the timezone that the user picked:

```
Time.zone = "Hawaii"
```

You then use the this new time zone to parse time time:

```
hawaii_time = Time.zone.parse("6:00")
```

If we now print out `hawaii_time` we get something similar to (we have HST -10:00 which means it is correct):

```
Mon, 15 Aug 2011 06:00:00 HST -10:00
```

You now use the rails `in_time_zone` method to convert to your app's timezone:

```
local_time = hawaii_time.in_time_zone(Rails.configuration.time_zone)
```

If we print out `local_time` we'll get something similar to (we have ICT +07:00 which is correct for Bangkok):

```
Mon, 15 Aug 2011 23:00:00 ICT +07:00
```

We can now reset the timezone of our app back to its original value:

```
Time.zone = Rails.configuration.time_zone
```

Comment: Wow Skorks that is the most awesome well explained answer I have ever seen. Absolutely awesome. Thank you soooooo much.